# How to add the username,telephone number with password in Firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and I'm trying to add a username,telephone number, the database with the password. 
s there a way to do it or is createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function only for email and password?

Answer (score 0):

Given the method name `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, it would seem that is creates a user with an email and a password.

There is nothing built into Firebase to create a user based on a user name as phone number. The two most common approaches are:

1. Use an existing Firebase identity provider to create a user based on for example the [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), and then [store the additional information in the database](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+store+additional+user+data) associated with that user.
2. [Create your own identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) that does precisely what you want.